# shebang on vagrant mount doesn't work: bad interpreter: Invalid argument

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, macos, vagrant, shebang

I run in a strange problem if I try to execute a file inside vagrant mount, but not outside:

```bsh
$ cat test 
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('works!')

$ ls -la test 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 43 May 13 23:17 test

$ ./test 
bash: ./test: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Invalid argument

$ /usr/bin/env node test
works!

$ cp test /tmp/; cd /tmp/
$ ./test 
works!
```

Some details:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep workspace
home_vagrant_workspace /home/vagrant/workspace vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev 0 0

$ mount | grep workspace
home_vagrant_workspace on /home/vagrant/workspace type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev)
```

Tried also:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep workspace
home_vagrant_workspace /home/vagrant/workspace vboxsf defaults,dev,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0

$ mount | grep workspace
home_vagrant_workspace on /home/vagrant/workspace type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Guest:

```
$ uname -a
Linux vagrant 5.11.0-11-generic #12-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 1 19:26:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hirsute
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (development branch)"
```

Host: MacOS BigSur 11.3 (20E232)
Provider: VirtualBox

Vagrant snippet:

```
    config.vm.box = properties["data"]["machine"]["box"] // bento/ubuntu-21.04
    # Shared Folders Configuration
    if (properties["data"].include? "shared_folders")
        properties["data"]["shared_folders"].each do |folder, index|
            config.vm.synced_folder folder["item"]["host"], folder["item"]["guest"], id: index, owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant"
        end
    end
```

Any suggestions how to deal with that?

Comment: was your `test` script uploaded from a windows machine? i.e. does it have CRLF line-endings rather than just LF?

Comment: Nope. It's crafted by hand in vim. As you can see above just by changing the location from vboxsf script begin to work.

Comment: Interesting, does it also happen with `#!/usr/bin/env sh`?

Comment: Yes, and with `#!/bin/sh` too. Files are just not executable, very similar to "noexec" mount option, but with different error.

Comment: @AntonBessonov could it be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952612/mac-os-usr-bin-env-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted ? as I read your host is MacOS based

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `xattr` and `xattr -l` returns nothing.

Comment: You're mounting you (MacOS) host directory inside a Linux VM.  This does feel like it's a MacOS thing tripping it up. Perhaps security related.

Comment: Any solution here? Having same issue with Parallels Desktop - trying to run bash script on psf mounted volume on Arch Linux. At the same time everything works fine on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a change in the kernel that causes an incompatibility with Parallels Tools. [Related topic on the Parallels forum](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/execution-files-located-on-shared-folders-mount-with-exec.352815/). Perhaps it is the same root cause as the error you are getting in your setup.

The workaround is to just not directly execute script files (via `#!`) and instead invoke the interpreter directly, like `bash foo.sh` instead of `./foo.sh`.

Comment: Probably I was not precise enough. VirtualBox is used as provider. From the patch I see that it's very parallels specific.

Comment: Okay; the error is similar so I thought the two issues might be connected. Does the suggested workaround work for your Vagrant+VirtualBox setup?